# CMake undefined when running C++ process in Mathematica

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run C++ code through Mathematica. So far, I have:

```
PATH = "/Users/Jessica/git/QuadTree/build/";
SetDirectory[PATH];
RunProcess["./run.sh"]
```

Inside ./run.sh, I use CMake to build my C++ program:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

set -eu

mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
make
./QuadTree
```

When I run this through the terminal in the directory `/Users/Jessica/git/QuadTree/build/`, it runs perfectly fine. However, when I run the code above in Mathematica, I get

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 127, "StandardOutput" -> "", 
 "StandardError" -> 
  "/Users/Jessica/git/QuadTree/./run.sh: line 7: cmake: command not \
found
  "|>
```

I'm not sure why the command cannot be found, since I set the directory to the exact same one where the program can be run in the terminal. Does anyone have any suggestions?